# How i can set the encoding to UTF-8 in my web requests in the java code

Tags: android

this method make get request to server and return JSON response as string.

```
public static String getJSONString(String url) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(request);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "none";
}
```

This is my JSON response

```
07-18 19:34:53.816: I/MyResponse(27454): {"status":"ok","count":1,"pages":1,"category":{"id":7,"slug":"%d8%af%d9%83%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1-%d9%85%d8%b5%d8%b7%d9%81%d9%89-%d9%85%d8%ad%d9%85%d9%88%d8%af","title":"\u062f\u0643\u062a\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u0635\u0637\u0641\u0649 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u0648\u062f","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1},"posts":[{"id":39,"type":"post","slug":"%d9%83%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ae%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%ac-%d9%85%d9%86-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8%d9%88%d8%aa-2","url":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/%d9%83%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ae%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%ac-%d9%85%d9%86-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8%d9%88%d8%aa-2\/","status":"publish","title":"\u0643\u062a\u0627\u0628: \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0631\u0648\u062c \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0648\u062a","title_plain":"\u0643\u062a\u0627\u0628: \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0631\u0648\u062c \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0648\u062a","content":"<p>\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a \u062d\u0638\u0627 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u0628\u062e\u062a\u0627 \u0648\u0625\u0646\u0645\u0627 \u0647\u064a \u0642\u062f\u0631\u0629\u060c \u0623\u0628\u0648\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0641\u062a\u062d \u0625\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644 \u0645\u0646 \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644 \u0646\u0641\u0633\u0643\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u062c\u064a\u0626\u0643 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0628\u0647\u0627 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0646\u064a\u0627\u060c \u0648\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0633\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0647\u0627 \u0633\u0628\u064a\u0644\u0643.<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a \u062d\u0638\u0627 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u0628\u062e\u062a\u0627 \u0648\u0625\u0646\u0645\u0627 \u0647\u064a \u0642\u062f\u0631\u0629\u060c \u0623\u0628\u0648\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0641\u062a\u062d \u0625\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644 \u0645\u0646 \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644 \u0646\u0641\u0633\u0643\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u062c\u064a\u0626\u0643 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0628\u0647\u0627 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0646\u064a\u0627\u060c \u0648\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u062a\u0633\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0647\u0627 \u0633\u0628\u064a\u0644\u0643.<\/p>\n","date":"2014-07-18 05:44:01","modified":"2014-07-18 05:44:01","categories":[{"id":7,"slug":"%d8%af%d9%83%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1-%d9%85%d8%b5%d8%b7%d9%81%d9%89-%d9%85%d8%ad%d9%85%d9%88%d8%af","title":"\u062f\u0643\u062a\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u0635\u0637\u0641\u0649 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u0648\u062f","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","thumbnail":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/429145_10150655987184630_1108330336_n-672x372.jpg","custom_fields":{},"thumbnail_size":"post-thumbnail","thumbnail_images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/429145_10150655987184630_1108330336_n.jpg","width":960,"height":373},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/429145_10150655987184630_1108330336_n-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/429145_10150655987184630_1108330336_n-300x116.jpg","width":300,"height":116},"post-thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/ovtraining.net\/wpf\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/429145_10150655987184630_1108330336_n-672x3
```

Arabic language returned like this "slug":"%d8%af%d9%83%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1-%d9%85%d8%b5%d8%b7%d9%81%d9%89-%d9%85%d8%ad%d9%85%d9%88%d8%af"
How i can handle this issue??

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
 String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 String utf8String=new String(result.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

Another way would be by setting a header to your request but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```
String in = "%d8%af%d9%83%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1";  
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(in, "UTF-8");
```